# Running Conversion Script - Modelica 4.0

Tags: modelica

Does anyone have experience converting Modelica 3.x files to the new 4.0 library standard?  There is a link to a script, yet I am not sure how to apply it.

https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/blob/master/Modelica/Resources/Scripts/Conversion/ConvertModelica_from_3.2.3_to_4.0.0.mos

I am using Wolfram System Modeller 12.1 on a Mac, yet if needs must, can use OMEdit on either Mac or W10.

Any help to overcome my ignorance would be great.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60591569/dymola-conversion-script-run-script-manually

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand from discussion with developers conversion scripts aren't supported yet in Wolfram System Modeler.

I haven't heard as much about that topic from OMEdit, but the status seems similar based on https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/5297

The MSL 4.0.0 was even delayed a bit to give tools a bit of extra time to implement this feature. (That also allowed the scripts to be checked in additional ways with Dymola.)